# how to embed janrain widget on your salesforce community page?

Tags: apex, community

I am trying to get Janrain social widget on my salesforce community login page? Any pointers on it will be helpful?

Comment: Please be more specific regarding the problem/s that you're having. I'm sure if you typed this on google you would find starting point information. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Till now i have created a Janrain Account and configured Facebook,Google,Yahoo Providers by following the steps mentioned in Janrain documentation. Next step is we will get a code which we can use it in Salesforce community login page. But not finding a way to use that code to display the widget.

Comment: Hi Sunny, what have you been searching for so far on the web? I did a quick search on "salesforce janrain" and found this: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_janrain.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Hi KoenVM, I have followed the same link and made all the changes. The only thing i did not get is how to customize the community login page to support the widget that Janrain offers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two links which provide complete details of integrating Janrain

http://developers.janrain.com/how-to/social-login/create-a-social-login-application/

http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sso_provider_janrain.htm&language=en_US#sso_provider_janrain)

In brief:

You need to sign in to janrain website and copy the widget code to use in Salesforce.
You have to setup auth provider in Salesforce to authenticate with facebook and other social sites. Detailed description is in url shared above.